# How do I make this procedure generate random times (HH:MM:SS) but with the current date?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need this procedure to generate 10M random timestamps but it has to use the current date each time it is called, how do i do this? I know that there's a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE producer() 
    

    BEGIN
        DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 0;
        WHILE a < 10000000 DO
            INSERT INTO CaseLog (`TIMESTAMP_IN`) 
            VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-22 00:00:00')+FLOOR(RAND()*86399))
            );
            SET a = a+1;
        END WHILE;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CURRENT_DATE()` to get today's date, and use that instead of the hard-coded date.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE producer() 

    BEGIN
        DECLARE today_timestamp INT;
        SET today_timestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE());
        DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 0;
        WHILE a < 10000000 DO
            INSERT INTO CaseLog (`TIMESTAMP_IN`) 
            VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(today_timestamp+FLOOR(RAND()*86400)));
            SET a = a+1;
        END WHILE;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also, you should multiply `RAND()` by `86400`, not `86399`. The result of `RAND()` is always less than `1.0`, so you don't have to worry that it will return `86400`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried this procedure but I am getting this error message: ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'today' Also do I understand it correctly that the current date would be saved into the variable today_timestamp and then used in FROM_UNIXTIME()?

Comment: Sorry, I was changing the variable name as I went along, and only changed it in one place.

Comment: I figured that would be the issue because it wasn't being used anywhere, it works now, thank you so much! Just one little follow-up question, do the DECLARE statements have to be below each other or is my query just bugged? Because when they weren't below each other, I've got a syntax error.

Comment: You can only put `DECLARE` at the beginning of a `BEGIN` block.